# variables globales en laravel

Tags: laravel, session, controller

en un controlador realizo operaciones para calcular unos datos
el cotrolador es una clase, dentro de la clase hay una funcion y dentro de la funcion hago

```
$datoaguardar=$resultadodelaoperacion;
```

una vez realizo esos cálculos voy a una vista con varios botones, en uno de esos botones quiero llamar a otro controlador diferente que realiza una accion completamente independiente pero necesita el valor de **$datoaguardar**

el caso es que si pongo session me sale 0 siempre salvo que ponga datoaguardar=23, pero si pongo

```
// Da como resultado: 0
$datoaguardar = $resultadodelaoperacion
```

para solucionarlo he guardado el valor en una tabla y luego lo recupero en el nuevo controlador pero me parece una practica un poc rebuscada

sabeis cómo puedo trabajar con una variable predefinida en algún lugar y que luego se pueda utilizar (lectura y modificacion) en cualquier otro lugar de la aplicacion?

todo esto en laravel 8 claro

muchas gracias a todos, sois una comunidad maravillosa

Comment: Pero el valor de la variable $datoaguardar la envías a la primera vista?, y en esa vista, el valor llega correctamente?, otro punto a tener en cuenta es que podes enviar esa variable al nuevo controlador por medio de un parámetro a su ruta correspondiente, salvo que quieras evitarte pasar la variable por medio de la vista para "garantizar" que no se modifica por el camino. Otra cosa que ayudaría es que muestres algo de codigo, por ejemplo como definis las variables de sesion, para ver si el error no está allí.

Comment: puede colocar mas código para comprender mejor el problema, con solo texto es difícil como responder a tu problema, es necesario mostrar el flujo de trabajo y los datos